# Double for loop in Javascript inner array length

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a function that takes in a string and changes each letters value to a "(" if the character is not duplicated in the string, and a ")" if the character does have a duplicate present in the string. I have decided to go an unconventional route to solve this problem but I am running in to an issue with a double for loop. From what I understand, the inner for loop in javascript does not have access to the variables outside of the loop. I want to loop through every item in an array twice but I'm not sure what to set the inner loops length as.

Here is my code:

```
function sortAndChange(word) {
const splitter = word.toLowerCase().split("");
//let jSplitter = word.toLowerCase().split("").length;
let endResult = "";
let truthArray = [];

for(i = 0; i < splitter.length; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < splitter.length; j++){
        console.log(j);
        if(splitter[i] == splitter[j]){
            truthArray.push(true);
        } else {
            truthArray.push(false);
        }
    }
    console.log(truthArray);
    truthArray.every(item => item === false) ? endResult += "(" : endResult += ")";
    truthArray = [];
}
console.log(endResult);
}
```

Expected Result:

```
sortAndChange("Success") //expected output: ")())())"
sortAndChange("easy") //expected output: "(((("
```

Comment: do you have an example and the wanted result?

Comment: Can you please give an input and expected output?

Comment: "the inner for loop in javascript does not have access to the variables outside of the loop" that's incorrect.

Comment: just noting, in both of those loops you only ever increment `i`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that in following steps:

- Convert string to array using `split` and use `map()` on it.
- Compare the `indexOf()` and `lastIndexOf()` to check if its duplicate or not.
- Return the `)` or `(` based on ur condition. And then at last `join` the array

```js
function sortAndChange(str){
  let arr = str.toLowerCase().split('')
  return arr.map(x => {
    //if its not duplicated
    if(arr.indexOf(x) === arr.lastIndexOf(x)){
      return '('
    }
    //If its duplicated
    else{
      return ')'
    }
  }).join('');
}

console.log(sortAndChange("Success")) //expected output: ")())())"
console.log(sortAndChange("easy")) //expected output: "(((("
```

Comment: @klaurtar1 First you loop through all the values in `map` and then again in `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` so its `O(n ^ 2)`. If you want linear time-complexity I could think of it.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a object and keep a boolean value for later mapping the values.

This approach has two loops with **O(2n)**

```js
function sortAndChange(word) {
    word = word.toLowerCase();
    var map = [...word].reduce((m, c) => (m[c] = c in m, m), {});
    return Array
        .from(word, c => '()'[+map[c]])
        .join('');
}

console.log(sortAndChange("Success")); // )())())
console.log(sortAndChange("easy"));    // ((((
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following snippet and comments

```js
function sortAndChange(str) {
  // we create an array containing the characters on the string
  // so we can use Array.reduce
  return str.split('').reduce((tmp, x, xi) => {
    // we look if the character is duplicate in the string
    // by looking for instance of the character
    if (str.slice(xi + 1).includes(x.toLowerCase())) {
      // Duplicate - we replace every occurence of the character
      tmp = tmp.replace(new RegExp(x, 'gi'), ')');
    } else {
      // Not duplicate
      tmp = tmp.replace(new RegExp(x, 'gi'), '(');
    }

    return tmp;
  }, str);
}

console.log(sortAndChange('Success')); //expected output: ")())())"
console.log(sortAndChange('Easy')); //expected output: "(((("
```

Comment: Your output is wrong. `I` the first letter is not duplicated to it should be replaced by `(`

Comment: @MaheerAli Fixed it. Had my characters wrong with lowercase. thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be achieved using a combination of `regex` and the `map` construct in javascript:

```js
const input = "this is a test";
const characters = input.toLowerCase().split('');
const transformed = characters.map(currentCharacter => {
  const regexpression = new RegExp(currentCharacter, "g");
  if (input.toLowerCase().match(regexpression || []).length > 1) return ')'
  return '(';
}).join("");
console.log(transformed);
```

Answer (score 0):

1) use `Array.from` to convert to array of chars

2) use `reduce` to build object with key-value pairs as char in string and ( or ) as value based on repetition .

3) Now convert original string to result string using the chars from above object.

```js
function sortAndChange(str) {
  const str_arr = Array.from(str.toLowerCase());
  const obj = str_arr.reduce(
    (acc, char) => ((acc[char] = char in acc ? ")" : "("), acc),
    {}
  );
  return str_arr.reduce((acc, char) => `${acc}${obj[char]}`, "");
}

console.log(sortAndChange("Success")); // ")())())"
console.log(sortAndChange("easy")); // ((((
```